# Plot multiple columns combined

Tags: excel, plot, charts

I've tried to find an answer to this question, but I'm stuck...

I've several sheets where I collect statistic for my trading account performance, where each sheet represents a single month. All the sheets are alike (in terms of table structure) but number of rows is different.

One of the columns represents my current equity and change after each trade.

I would like to plot the values of this column from ALL the months sheets to a single chart in a continues order.
 - The data from January comes first.
 - The data from February after it
 - The data from March after and so on.

End result: I would like to get an equity curve of my account.

How can I do that?

Comment: the easiest way is to summarize the data on one sheet and graph that.

Comment: ok. Assume I summarize everything on on sheet. If I understand it correctly, I should summarize all the columns from different sheet in a single column.  How can I do it if the length of each column is different?